# Excel drawn in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks, excel

I was wondering if anyone has any ideas of how I would go about drawing a spreadsheet outline with pstricks or tikz?
It is for a maths exam where students are asked to interpret a spreadsheet, as shown below.
[image]

I originally tried just a screenshot, but it was too lossy.
Apologies, but I can't even provide a MWE!

Comment: How accurate does it have to be, couldn't a normal table work?

Comment: Why not take a screenshot and insert it as an image, which is much simpler?

Comment: @AndréC, while I agree on the principle, this is already explained by the OP (though I am pretty sure one can do a *not so lossy* screenshot :) )

Comment: @BambOo Indeed, I hadn't read it properly. There is a method to export an Excel file in jpg format: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/save-a-chart-as-a-picture-254bbf9a-1ce1-459f-914a-4902e8ca9217

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pas-tableur}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tableur[4]{A,B,C}
    \celtxt[l]{C}{2}{dd}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```